# Logout in a thymeleaf client when we use oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, resttemplate, spring-oauth2

I have 3 application, one for authorization, one with resource (api rest) and one client in thymeleaf who consume the rest.

When I log out of my client, that don't seem to be a real log out, because when i click on login, that login me directly... use previous user.

I took Baeldung example, who are similar to mine and has same issue.

Authorization server
https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-authorization-server

Resource server
https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-resource-server-1

Thymeleaf client
https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/clients-thymeleaf/oauth-ui-authorization-code-thymeleaf

In the Authorization server I have

```
@Controller
public class TokenController {

    @Resource(name = "tokenServices")
    private ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Resource(name = "tokenStore")
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/oauth/token/revokeById/{tokenId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void revokeToken(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String tokenId) {
        tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/tokens")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getTokens() {
        Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientId("sampleClientId");
        return Optional.ofNullable(tokens).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream().map(OAuth2AccessToken::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tokens/revokeRefreshToken/{tokenId:.*}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String revokeRefreshToken(@PathVariable String tokenId) {
        if (tokenStore instanceof JdbcTokenStore) {
            ((JdbcTokenStore) tokenStore).removeRefreshToken(tokenId);
        }
        return tokenId;
    }

}
```

In the thymeleaf client I have

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor(clientService));
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

How to really log out from the thymeleaf (token must be surely removed?)

Comment: It should be the rest API. Security is meant to secure the resource which is served by your API.

Answer (score 0):

"Security" needs to be on every layer on your applications. But I guess by your post that you mean the authentication layer.

If you don't want your REST API to be available for use by everyone, you should add an authentication layer to it and at least a CORS policy. Think API keys, OAuth or plain old username/password authentication.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security as a starting point